# Need help getting the value of object length in array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, object

I have an array that looks something like this.

```
0: Object { age: 1.22128, initials: "YY", major: "Internet Content & Information" }
​
1: Object { age: 0.623491, initials: "RAM", major: "Banks Diversified" }
​
2: Object { age: 3.47226, initials: "W", major: "Internet Retail" }
​
3: Object { age: 0.10981, initials: "DAM", major: "Communication Equipment" }
​
4: Object { age: 0, symbol: initials", major: "Software Application" }
​
5: Object { age: 0.82384, initials: "SAM", major: "Internet Content & Information" }
​
6: Object { age: 1.62574, initials: "LISA", major: "Internet Content & Information" }
​
7: Object { age: 0, initials: "AN", college: "major Content & Information" }
​
8: Object { age: 1.34786, initials: "PAM", major: "REIT Retail" }
​
9: Object { age: 0, initials: "DREW", major: "Software—Infrastructure" }
```

What I wanted to do was classify the majors into a chart and I was able to do so using this code. below.

```
      var data = array, 
  result = _(data)
  .groupBy('major')
  .map((group, major) => 
      ({ industry, children: _.map(group, ({ initials: major, age }) => ({ major, age })) }))
  .value(),
// final = [{ name: "Children Array", children: result }];
final = result
```

The chart I am using to allocate the initials into majors takes in values like this.

```
  const data = [
  {
    type: 'Retail',
    value: 38,
  },
  {
    type: 'Software',
    value: 5,
  },
  {
    type: 'Engineering',
    value: 35,
  },
  {
    type: 'Real Estate',
    value: 15,
  },
  {
    type: 'HealthCare',
    value: 7,
  },
]
```

I was able to get it in an array looking like this, using the code excerpt above.

```
(18) […]
​
0: Object { major: "Internet Content & Information", children: (5) […] }
​
1: Object { major: "Banks Diversified", children: (1) […] }
​
2: Object { major: "Internet Retail", children: (1) […] }
​
3: Object { major: "Communication Equipment", children: (2) […] }
​
4: Object { major: "Software Application", children: (3) […] }
```

The children indicated how many initials were in that major, is there a way I can create a new array that mimic the way the chart takes in the code so I could have the major as the type and the children value as the value in the chart.

Would also be happy if someone could alternatively help me turn the array at the top into the data syntax for the chart.
Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first create object with keys as all mejors and then loop through it to create array you want
see below snippet

```js
const input = [
  { age: 1.22128, initials: "YY", major: "Internet Content & Information" },
  { age: 0.623491, initials: "RAM", major: "Banks Diversified" },
  { age: 3.47226, initials: "W", major: "Internet Retail" },
  { age: 0.10981, initials: "DAM", major: "Communication Equipment" },
  { age: 0, initials: "SHA", major: "Software Application" },
  { age: 0.82384, initials: "SAM", major: "Internet Content & Information" },
  { age: 1.62574, initials: "LISA", major: "Internet Content & Information" },
  { age: 0, initials: "AN", major: "major Content & Information" },
  { age: 1.34786, initials: "PAM", major: "REIT Retail" },
  { age: 0, initials: "DREW", major: "Software—Infrastructure" },
];

const obj = {};
input.forEach((row) => {
  if (!obj[row.major]) obj[row.major] = 1;
  obj[row.major]++;
});
const output = [];
for (var key in obj) {
  output.push({ type: key, value: obj[key] });
}
console.log(output);
```